# How to hide table row with empty cell with php

Tags: php, html, pdf, html-table

I have htmltopdf code from developers and there is a part with a table that consists of 'Question' and 'Answer', so if the answer is empty I need to hide the row.

Here is a part of my code:

```
$pdfHTML = '<table border="1"><tbody>';

        foreach($arAnswer as $items){

            $pdfHTML .= '<tr>';
                $pdfHTML .= '<td>';
                    $pdfHTML .= htmlspecialcharsEx($items['0']['TITLE']);
                $pdfHTML .= '</td>';
                $pdfHTML .= '<td>';
                    foreach($items as $item){
                        if($item['USER_TEXT']){
                            $pdfHTML .= htmlspecialcharsEx($item['USER_TEXT']);
                        }else if( ($answerText = trim($item['ANSWER_TEXT'])) ){
                            $pdfHTML .= htmlspecialcharsEx($answerText);
                        }
                        $pdfHTML .= '<br>';
                    }
                $pdfHTML .= '</td>';
            $pdfHTML .= '</tr>';
        }

        $pdfHTML .= '</tbody></table>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can check all items inside answers and then decide to add or not new line

```
$pdfHTML = '<table border="1"><tbody>';

foreach ($arAnswer as $items) {
    $isAnswer = false;
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if (trim($item['ANSWER_TEXT'])) {
            $isAnswer = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($isAnswer) {
        $pdfHTML .= '<tr>';
        $pdfHTML .= '<td>';
        $pdfHTML .= htmlspecialcharsEx($items['0']['TITLE']);
        $pdfHTML .= '</td>';
        $pdfHTML .= '<td>';
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item['USER_TEXT']){
                $pdfHTML .= htmlspecialcharsEx($item['USER_TEXT']);
            }
            if (!empty($item['ANSWER_TEXT'])) {
                $pdfHTML .= htmlspecialcharsEx($item['ANSWER_TEXT']);
            }
            $pdfHTML .= '<br>';
        }
        $pdfHTML .= '</td>';
        $pdfHTML .= '</tr>';
    }

}

$pdfHTML .= '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: Man, thank you so much you are the best. It perfectly worked for me! How can add the same condition for USER_TEXT at the same time?

Comment: @ZhalgasBekpaev Good! Vote up, bro! if you want to show line when ANSWER_TEXT _AND_ USER_TEXT both are not empty in the same time, you can change `if (trim($item['ANSWER_TEXT']))` to `if (trim($item['ANSWER_TEXT']) && trim($item['USER_TEXT']))`. If one of those not empty cjange `&&` to `||`

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add a `empty` check, for example:

```php
foreach ($arAnswer as $items) {
    $pdfHTML .= '<tr>';
    $pdfHTML .= '<td>';
    $pdfHTML .= htmlspecialcharsEx($items['0']['TITLE']);
    $pdfHTML .= '</td>';
    $pdfHTML .= '<td>';
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item['USER_TEXT']) {
            $pdfHTML .= htmlspecialcharsEx($item['USER_TEXT']);
        }
        if (!empty($item['ANSWER_TEXT'])) {
            $pdfHTML .= htmlspecialcharsEx($item['ANSWER_TEXT']);
        }
        $pdfHTML .= '<br>';
    }
    $pdfHTML .= '</td>';
    $pdfHTML .= '</tr>';
}

$pdfHTML .= '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work for me? i mean you add empty check for <td>, but i want to hide rows in table.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this add class , make it hide using jquery. like below example :

```
//PHP :
$pdfHTML = '';

foreach ($arAnswer as $items) {
    $pdfHTML .= '<tr>';
    $pdfHTML .= '<td>';
    $pdfHTML .= htmlspecialcharsEx($items['0']['TITLE']);
    $pdfHTML .= '</td>';
    $pdfHTML .= '<td>';
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item['USER_TEXT']) {
            $pdfHTML .= htmlspecialcharsEx($item['USER_TEXT']);
        }
        if (!empty($item['ANSWER_TEXT'])) {
            $pdfHTML .= htmlspecialcharsEx($item['ANSWER_TEXT']);
        }
//add empty div with class with to hide row

        if (empty($item['ANSWER_TEXT'])) {
            $pdfHTML .= '<div class="hide_table_row"></div>';
        }
        $pdfHTML .= '<br>';
    }
    $pdfHTML .= '</td>';
    $pdfHTML .= '</tr>';
}

$pdfHTML .= '</tbody></table>';
```

//jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//hide row (parent tr)
  $(".hide_table_row").closest('tr').hide();
});
```

Comment: Task "How to hide table row with empty cell with php". Decision - use JQuery. Really?